# Class added in one handler and already activating another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*About the title: I really could not think of a beter way to describe this.*

I have this webpage [here](http://hunpony.hu/today/faq/hu/), and this is the jQuery code I use:

```
$('a[class]').click(function(){
    var clas = $(this).attr('class');

    $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)).fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
    $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').fadeTo('fast',0.3);
    $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
    $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)+'a'+':hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').addClass('faded') //the class gets added
});
$('p:not(p.faded)').click(function(){ //right after it fires this
    $('p.faded').fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
    $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
});
```

HTML

```
<p id="q1">1. <a class="q1">Nem látom a kedvenc karakterem, hozzá tudod adni?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q1a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Persze. Írj egy e-mail-t a <a href="mailto:djdavid98+mlptoday@gmail.com?subject=MLP Today Karakterkérés" target="_blank">djdavid98@gmail.com</a> címre a karakter nevével.
        <br>
        <span style="color:red">OC-kat és fillyket NEM adok hozzá.</span>
    </span>
    </p>

    <p id="q2">2. <a class="q2">Hogyan tudok karaktert választani?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q2a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Látogass el a <a href="../../img/?from=faq_hu">Karakterválasztás</a> oldalra, ahol.
        <br>
        Haználhatod továbbá a "<i>Véletlenszerű karakter</i>" linket is.
    </span>
    </p>

    <p id="q3">3. <a class="q3">Mi ennek az oldalnak a célja/alapötlete?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q3a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Eredetileg a <a href="http://milyennapvanma.hu/" target="_blank">milyennapvanma.hu</a> weboldal pónisított változataként indult,
        <br>
        de azóta már nagy mértékben továbbfejlődött az oldal.
    </span>
</p>
```

As you can see on the [page](http://hunpony.hu/today/faq/hu/), clicking on any of the numbered links will instantly show & hide, indicating that both of the above code runs, but the second only should run when the user clicks the text/link again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add stopPropagation() this link here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GSwDN/

```
$('a[class]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var clas = $(this).attr('class');

    $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)).fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
    $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').fadeTo('fast',0.3);
    $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
    $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)+'a'+':hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').addClass('faded') //the class gets added
});
$('p:not(p.faded)').click(function(){ //right after it fires this
    $('p.faded').fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
    $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
});
```

your code can be better/cleaned up but when you click the anchor, it bubbles up to the parent p which activates the click on the p and that's why you see both events firing

Comment: You can also `return false` at the end of the click handler

Comment: it's true you could return false, you would not need the stopPropagation if you return false since return false kills everything

Answer (score 2):

For the blinking effect I would suggest using CSS3 functionality.

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'blink' {
0% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
50% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0); }
100% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
}
.animate {
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: blink;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;   
}
```

I would then add this class to the button inside onclick event:

```
$('a[class]').click(function(e){
  $(this).addClass('animate')  
}
```

This saves you time but also makes your JS look cleaner.

Comment: I don't use any blinking effects on the page, only fading in and out things, which _may_ look like it's blinking but it's not.