# jQuery code behaves wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

jQuery is not working the way it should and is completely ignoring the logic.

If I click a link, it shows up the given description, and fades the other menus.
If I click the same link again, it should hide that description, and fade the other links back in.

But instead it just hides the text, and doesn't fade them back in.
When running the code alone from the console and when you click on the whitespace next to the paragraphs, it works just fine.

[Site for reference](http://hunpony.hu/today/hu/faq/)

jQuery:

```
    $('a[class]').click(function(){
    var clas = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)).fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
        $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').fadeTo('fast',0.3);
        $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
        $('#'+clas.substring(0,2)+'a'+':hidden').fadeIn('slow');
        $('p:not(#'+clas.substring(0,2)+')').addClass('faded');
        return false;
    });
    $('p:not(p.faded)').click(function(){
        $('.ans:visible').toggle('slow');
        $('p[class="faded"]').fadeTo('fast',1).removeClass('faded');
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <p id="q1">1. <a class="q1">Nem látom a kedvenc karakterem, hozzá tudod adni?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q1a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Persze. Írj egy e-mail-t a <a href="mailto:djdavid98+mlptoday@gmail.com?subject=MLP Today Karakterkérés" target="_blank">djdavid98@gmail.com</a> címre a karakter nevével.
        <br>
        <span style="color:red">OC-kat és fillyket NEM adok hozzá.</span>
    </span>
    </p>

    <p id="q2">2. <a class="q2">Hogyan tudok karaktert választani?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q2a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Látogass el a <a href="../../img/?from=faq_hu">Karakterválasztás</a> oldalra, ahol kiválaszthatod a kedvenced.
        <br>
        Haználhatod továbbá a "<i>Véletlenszerű karakter</i>" linket is.
    </span>
    </p>

    <p id="q3">3. <a class="q3">Mi ennek az oldalnak a célja/alapötlete?</a>
    <br>
    <span id="q3a" style="display:none;" class="ans">
        Eredetileg a <a href="http://milyennapvanma.hu/" target="_blank">milyennapvanma.hu</a> weboldal pónisított változataként indult,
        <br>
        de azóta már nagy mértékben továbbfejlődött az oldal.
    </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: without reading the code, I honestly think, *you* behave wrong.

Comment: If you see yourself using a bunch of selectors over an over, it means it's a good time to think about caching those in a variable and referencing the variable. It will make your code cleaner, more readable, thus you'll get a better chance for people to get interested in your code.

Comment: @pimvdb That would break the code because it would reffer to (example)

`$('# q2a:hidden').fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: @DJDavid98: Yeah sorry, I thought it referred to the `<a>` elements. Perhaps try removing `return false` as it prevents propagating to the second handler.

Comment: @pimvdb Well there was a discussion about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313599/class-added-in-one-handler-and-already-activating-another-one), and so I need that.

Comment: When you write `$("p:not(p.faded)').click(...)` it binds the handler to the not-faded elements when the DOM is first loaded.  The handlers don't change as you add and remove classes dynamically.  To get that, you should delegate using `on()`.

Comment: @Barmar Tried `on()` and it doesn't work with that either.

Comment: The reference page doesn't work for me. Console has messages "Uncaught ReferenceError: longtime is not defined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined".

Comment: @Barmar Fixed it, try now. The `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined` error is because this page is run in a plugin called "Fancybox" as an iframe, and the close link is there to close that. Of course it's not defined.

Comment: If there really is a bug in jQuery report it using their bug tracker at http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket?redirectedfrom=, not on SO. If there isn't a bug, as it seems from everyone else's comments, fix your code instead of complaining.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in the second click handler, it's never reached.

Comment: really? `<center>`? we're no longer in 1988...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I admire your self-confidence: your code doesn't work so you assume the problem is with jQuery.

In your code, this statement:

```
$('p:not(p.faded)').click(function(){
```

...binds a click handler to any elements that don't have the `"faded"` class *at that moment*. Which would be all elements since none are faded initially. If you want it to apply only to elements that have not later had that class added you need to use a delegated handler which you assign via `.on()` (or `.delegate()` if using jQuery older than 1.7, or `.live()` if using a ridiculously old jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'p:not(p.faded)'), function() {
```

Ideally you wouldn't bind the handler to `document`, you'd use the closest anscestor of the paragraphs in question, but since you haven't shown that much markup I'll leave that part to you.

Also though, you `return false;` from your click handler on the anchor elements, which prevents the click event from propagating up to the paragraphs anyway.

However, I think you're making the whole thing more complicated than you need to. The following code gets the job done:

```
var $questions = $('p'); // add class selectors here

$questions.click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
       isOpen = $this.hasClass('open');

   $this.fadeTo('fast',1).toggleClass('open',!isOpen)
        .find('span.ans').toggle('slow');
   $questions.not(this).fadeTo('fast', isOpen ? 1 : 0.2)
                       .removeClass('open')
                       .find('span.ans').hide('slow');
});
```

​
That is, when any paragraph is clicked, figure out whether it already has the answer open. Then make sure the clicked one is visible, and toggle its answer. Then take all of its sibling paragraphs and fade them in or out as appropriate and hide their answer.

Where I've put the comment "add class selectors here" it would be good to add a class to identify which paragraphs in your document are the questions.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DxFDP/2

Comment: +1 to "I admire your self-confidence: your code doesn't work so you assume the problem is with jQuery."

Comment: I have a problem. There is an other span inside the first one in the first question. This hides that when displaying the text.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have used the `"ans"` class in the selector in the two `.find()` statements. Answer and demo updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would **never use jQuery to apply styles** to the code, but simple add and remove classes...

**It will get messy**, and sometime, we can simplify instead of complicate things.

here is **simple example**: http://jsbin.com/amiloc/1/

the same, but without `<li>`'s: http://jsbin.com/amiloc/3/

added colors so we know what's going on "under the hood", will let you judge by yourself.

Comment: Your answer would be great if I were using list elements. I actually wanted to use classes, but then I would've lost jQuery's fade animations.

Comment: using `<li>` or not, you will get the same thing if you set the proper CSS... I would never use a `<p>`aragraph as that's intended for showing text, not creating blocks... just use `<div>` in each answer and you will have the same